# FME Oracle SDE Invalid column definition

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, oracle-spatial

I am using FME on daily basis working with sde feature classes.
Sometime I am receiving data with more then hundred columns and when working I receive the following error.

> The error number from Arc Objects is: '-2147216067'. The error message
> from Arc Objects is: {Invalid column definition [ORA-04043: ..

I am wondering if there is a way in FME to detect which column is giving this issue.
I do not have access to SQL Developer in my workplace so cannot check there. All I can do to fix this issue is to divide the columns into half and create a temporary feature class and then do the same till I get the culprit column.

Comment: This might be one for Safe Support. this other answer notes double quotes was missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515173/error-ora-04043-object-table-name-does-not-exist-when-describing-any-table-wit

Comment: Is that error occurring upon writing to the database? Can you cross reference your field names against the Oracle Reserved words? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: So yes that is one of the way to do it, but to be honest matching it with a list of reserved words is a bit difficult some times when you have more then hundred columns. 
I mean i have a  way around but just wondering if some champ has created a logger/transformer to pin point the column causing error.